# Can I deploy CloudFoundry on a collection of local PCs?

Tags: openstack, cloud-foundry

I know that I can run [PCF Dev](https://pivotal.io/pcf-dev) on a single VM. 
But I have a few old PCs that aren't doing anything.
It looks like [PCF](https://pivotal.io/platform) needs to run on VMs provided by AWS, Azure, Google, OpenStack, or VMware. So maybe I would need to install something like [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/software/) on my PCs first - perhaps with [Ubuntu/MAAS/Juju](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/01/21/introduction-deploying-openstack-on-maas-1-9-with-juju/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only bare-metal type solution I've seen for Bosh -> https://www.cloudfoundry.org/bosh-rackhd-cpi-running-cloud-foundry-on-bare-metal-with-bosh-2/.  Otherwise, you're going to need one of the virtualization layers supported by a Bosh CPI.

The next step up from PCF Dev would probably be [Bosh Lite](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/).  Beyond that, perhaps try the [Virtualbox CPI](https://bosh.io/docs/virtualbox-cpi.html)?  Both should run on a single server or laptop.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your answer led me to https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/bosh-rackhd-cpi-release/wiki/Tutorial:-How-to-deploy-Cloud-Foundry-on-Bare-Metal-Machine(s) which goes into a bit more detail.